# How to get all the hyperlinks but ignore the links of images

Tags: java, css-selectors, jsoup

I want to get all the hyperlinks of a webpage with Jsoup. Meanwhile, I want to ignore all the hyperlinks of images. Is it possible to add more restrictions for getElementsByTag?

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).timeout(1000).get();
links = doc.getElementsByTag("a").not("[src]");
```

Answer (score 0):

If your images are linked with `a` tags using `src`-attribute (while *normal* links use `href`) use this:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).timeout(1000).get();
Elements links = doc.select("a[href]"); // Only select 'a'-tags with 'href' attribute
```

See [here](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax) for jsoup selector api.